# What's the difference of normal index and FTS in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, indexing, full-text-search

Both use index to speed up string searching. So what's the difference?

In the [docs for `CREATE INDEX`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), there's no mention of `tokenization`, which makes me think that normal indices on text columns only speed up "=" queries, instead of more sophisticated `MATCH` query that can match words inside paragraphs, but I can't find any source that confirm this.

Comment: Full text search versus a normal index lookup. Some reading: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which makes me think that normal indices on text columns only speed up "=" queries

In general standard B-Tree index on text column speeds up **[SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)** queries like:

```
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col = 'value'
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col LIKE 'value'
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col LIKE 'value%'
```

But not:

```
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%value%';  
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%value';
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE UPPER(col) = 'VALUE';
```

They could still benefit from Index Scan instead of reading table, but it will not be as fast as Index Seek.

Answer (score 2):

phrases order in a text is important in a normal lookup, You can't find `'aaa bbb'` when you search sth like:

```
Select * from table where text like 'bbb aaa'
```

but in a full-text search you can find it.